# Access Django Directories in Views

Tags: python, django

I am automatically generating a Word doc when a user enters a number into the front-end website. My starting goal was to have Django initiate a download of the doc, but that has been unsuccessful.

Now, I just want to save the file to the server and deliver the file location URL back to my JS so I can create a link for the user to click.

The front-end uses a AJAX call to pass the user-input back to the view. The trouble is with getting the path correct inside the Django view. Here's my view:

```
@login_required
@custom_header
def create_document(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Create a doc and return URI."""
```

I tried using [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view) method:

```
    doc_path = static('doc.docx')
```

^ That returns this error: **IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/doc.docx'**

I manually created the folders and doc.docx file, in both locations, so they do exist. As suggested [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975415/python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-ulastid-py-for-file-in), I changed it to this:

```
    doc_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'doc/doc.docx')
```

^ But that results in: **IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './app_folder/doc/doc.docx'**

Rest of the View:

```
    doc_name = doc.docx

    # Template on which the doc is based
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'doc/template.docx')

    form = CleanerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_input = form.cleaned_data.get('user_input')
        doc_context = requests.get(
            'https://MY_API_URI/user_input=%s' % user_input,
        )
    else:
        # Failure Actions

    # Generate doc with context
    print os.getcwd()
    template = DocxTemplate(tmpl_path)
    template.render(json.loads(doc_context.text))
    template.save(doc_path)

    return HttpResponse(doc_path)
```

Imports

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import json
import os
from .forms import CleanerForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.templatetags.static import static
```

My initial code (which doesn't work) to open the file was:

```
with open(doc_path) as this_doc:
    wrapper = File(this_doc)
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(doc_path)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(doc_path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % doc_name
```

Comment: I'm surprised you cannot automatically download your word file because I do it with pdfs.  Have you tried something like: `response = HttpResponse(mydata, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-word')` 
`response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=example.doc'` 
`return response`

Comment: And here's a link that should help with the static file url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view