# Python Flask upload file to app folder on server (heroku)

Tags: python, heroku

I need to upload an image file to a certain folder. It works fine on localhost but if I push the app to heroku it tells me:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/userimg/1-bild-1.jpg'
```

Which means it cant find the folder?

I need to store the image files there for a few seconds to perform some actions on theme. After that they will be sent to AWS and will be deleted from the folder.

Thats the code where I save the images into the folder:

```
i = 1
for key, file in request.files.iteritems():
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(str(current_user.id) + "-bild-"+ str(i) +".jpg")
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) 
        i = i + 1
```

Later I get the files from the folder like this:

```
for item in os.listdir(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])):
    if item.startswith(str(current_user.id)) and item.split(".")[0].endswith("1"):
        with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], item), "rb") as thefile:
            data = base64.b64encode(thefile.read())
            upload_image_to_aws_from_image_v3('MYBUCKET', "userimg/", data, new_zimmer, "hauptbild", new_zimmer.stadt, new_zimmer.id)
        os.remove(str(thefile.name))
```

That is the upload folder in app config:

`UPLOAD_FOLDER = "static/userimg/"`

Everything works fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the absolute path to the directory, because the path on the server is different.

You can run `heroku run bash` for your app through the CLI and check the directories with `dir`. Use then `cd ..` to go back or `cd *directory name*` to go into the directory.

I had to add

```
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

and replace all

```
os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
```

with

```
os.path.join(MYDIR + "/" + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
```

Some informations on the topic also here:
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975415/python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-ulastid-py-for-file-in)

Comment: Note that uploaded files will be discarded upon redeploying the app, or latest after 24 hours. See the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku